# How to convert a directory of JPGs to multi PDF files?

Tags: pdf, conversion, imagemagick

I'm searching for a batch command that will convert a directory of JPGs to many PDF files.
In order to convert JPGs to JPGs, i use the following command:

```
mkdir tmp; find . -name "*.jpg" -exec convert -resize 900x -quality 85% {} tmp/{} \;
```

Now i want to do the same, more or less but with PDFs. I don't want the result to be a single PDF with many pages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You get a command-line PDF converter, for example [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) is a great open source project at SourceForge.

Your command line will be similar to what you already presented in the question, but instead of calling `convert` you will call PDFCreator with appropriate command line options.

Comment: thanks, but i wonder - imagemagick knows how to convert JPGs to PDFs, now i just need that it won't combine them into a single file...

Comment: @ShaiEfrati - my bad, I haven't noticed the tags saying the question is for imagemagick. (I usually skip reading the tags.)